# Designing responsive analytic dashboad

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, dashboard

I'm planning on building a responsive analytic dashboad using `Bootstrap`. And I've found a beautiful desgin that fits my needs perfectly.

The problem is I'm very new to css and html, but I'm very eager to learn. All I need is advices.

So, for desgining this kind of dashboard, what should I pay attention to and using? I mean which Bootstrap control for the menu, the panel ...

[image]

The design : https://www.behance.net/gallery/6355085/dashboard-analytics

Thanks alot!